# Merging css for text color and link color

Tags: html, css, merge

I have a standard style where text is typically white and links are typically red. However, in some menus, I would the text and the links to be both white.

I have the following Html:

```
<div class='mydiv2'>
    Some text with some <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.mydiv2 {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.mydiv2 a {
    color: white;
}
```

Is there any way to merge the two above css statements into one?

The JsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BBVyN/).

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
.mydiv2, .mydiv2 a {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

The comma allows you to have multiple selectors for a CSS statement.

**EDIT:** As mentioned above in the comments, this feature is documented here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping.